# How to supply levels to step_num2factor for multiple numeric features in tidymodel parsnip?

Tags: r, function, tidymodels

Following is the recipe I am creating where I want to convert few numeric features to factors:

```
    house_recipe <- training(house_split) %>%
      recipe(log_sale_price ~ MSSubClass + OverallCond + LowQualFinSF) %>%
      step_num2factor(
        select(MSSubClass,OverallCond,LowQualFinSF),
          levels = list(fct_cd_mssbclass, fct_cd_ovcond, fct_cd_lwqfinsf)
      )
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Please provide a character vector of appropriate length for `levels`.

The levels have been passed as list in the code above. The definition of `levels` is as follows:

```
#create levels
fct_cd_mssbclass <- as.character(unique(sort(training(house_split)$MSSubClass)))
fct_cd_ovcond <- as.character(unique(sort(training(house_split)$OverallCond)))
fct_cd_lwqfinsf <- as.character(unique(sort(training(house_split)$LowQualFinSF)))
```

Please advise how to use this step function correctly. I didn't find any similar example in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: The `levels` argument expects a character vector, not a list. If the three different variables need to have different levels, I believe you'll to use `step_num2factor()` three times, once for each variable.

Comment: Thanks Julia! Just a suggestion won't it be better design to include all these similar step in one step function?

Comment: I definitely see what you're saying but currently the function isn't quite that flexible. If you would like to open a GitHub issue, we can consider that in our prioritization for future work!

Comment: Sure, I will.open a GitHub issue. Thank for your response!

Comment: Did you open the issue? Having to use step_num2factor() for each variable is very anti-recipes

Answer (score 3):

You can factor several variables at once with the function `step_mutate_at()`. It takes the variables you want to change and any function you want to use:
 `step_mutate_at(MSSubClass,OverallCond,LowQualFinSF, fn = factor)`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.